# Auto pagination does not display more elements on page (angularJs / JQuery)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, pagination

I am trying to make an auto pagination where, if the user gets to the bottom of the page and there are more elements to display, they get load (by 6) and, if there are not, the footer is displayed.

Problem seems to be where the other elements needs to be displayed, since the function is called and works (I think) properly, but the other cards are not displayed on the screen.

Can you tell me what am I missing here to make it work as its supposed to?

Here is what I have so far:

```
<!-- Mobile result cards -->
          <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" ng-show="loading && showMobileResults" ng-if="isMobile">
            <img class="loading-img" src="img/loading_animation.gif"/>
          </div>
          <div id="mobile-result-cards" class="col-xs-12 text-center hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" ng-show="!loading && showMobileResults">
              <p id="results-count">We found {{resultsPagination.totalEvents}} {{(resultsPagination.totalEvents===1)? 'result' : 'results'}}</p>
                <div class="search-results-cards">
                   <result-card-mobile ng-repeat="baEvent in eventsToDisplayPartial"
                                  ba-event="baEvent"
                                  ng-click="navigateToEventDetail(baEvent.id, baEvent.name)">
                    </result-card-mobile>
                    <div id="showMoreEventsMobile" class="col-xs-12 text-center" ng-show="showMoreEvents" style="margin: 20px auto; height: 50px;"></div>
                </div>
          </div>             
          <!-- End mobile result cards -->
```

and in the controller

```
var init = function(){
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        detectScroll();
    });
};

    var detectScroll = function(){
    var offY = $(document).scrollTop();
    console.log(offY);
    if(offY > $scope.distanceToScroll){
        $scope.showMoreEvts();
    }
};

var setMobileResults = function(){
    $scope.eventsToDisplayPartial = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        if($scope.eventsToDisplay[i] != "" && $scope.eventsToDisplay[i] != "undefined" && $scope.eventsToDisplay[i] != null){
            $scope.eventsToDisplayPartial.push($scope.eventsToDisplay[i]);
        }
    }
    if($scope.eventsToDisplay.length > tempNumber){
        tempNumber = tempNumber + 6;
        $scope.showMoreEvents = true;
        $scope.loading = true;
        //$scope.$apply($('#mobile-result-cards'));

    } else {
        $scope.showMoreEvents = false;
        $scope.loading = false;
    }
};

$scope.showMoreEvts = function(){
    $scope.showMoreEvents = false;
    //$scope.$apply($('#mobile-result-cards'));

    for (var i = (tempNumber - 6); i < tempNumber; i++){
        if($scope.eventsToDisplay[i] != "" && $scope.eventsToDisplay[i] != "undefined" && $scope.eventsToDisplay[i] != null){
            $scope.eventsToDisplayPartial.push($scope.eventsToDisplay[i]);
        }
    }
    if($scope.eventsToDisplay.length > tempNumber){
        tempNumber = tempNumber + 6;
        $scope.showMoreEvents = true;
        $scope.loading = true;
        $scope.distanceToScroll += 870;
        console.log($scope.distanceToScroll);
        //$scope.$apply($('#mobile-result-cards'));

    } else {
        $scope.showMoreEvents = false;
        $scope.loading = false;
    }
};

init();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are `detectScroll` and `$scope.showMoreEvts()` being called? Did you check by adding `console.log()` to these?

Comment: They are... I am not sure if that is what I was looking for, but calling apply to the array fixed the problem